# Dual of $\ell_\infty(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Given a Banach space $X$. Consider the space $\ell_\infty(X)$ which is the $\ell_\infty$-sum of countably many copies of $X$. Is there any accessible respresentation of the dual space $\ell_\infty(X)^*$? In particular, is this dual space isomorphic to the space of finitely additive $X^*$-valued measures on the powerset of $\mathbb N$ equipped with the semivariation norm?

Any references will be appreciated.

Comment: Is $E = X$ in your question?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no good description of the dual of $\ell_\infty(X)$ as far as I know.
If $X$ is finite dimensional, then the answer to your second question is yes.
Otherwise, it is no, for there is no way to define an action of a finitely additive $X^*$-valued measure on $\ell_\infty(X)$ if the ball of $X$ is not compact.